# pandas resample with function that returns an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

The `pd.resample` function accepts any function that goes from an array to a number as its `how` keyword argument (although that's not in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)). So the following example works well

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=60)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
print df.resample('10D', how=np.std, axis=0)
```

However, is there a way of doing the same thing with a function that returns an array? For example, if I try `df.resample('10D', how=np.fft.rfft, axis=0)` pandas will exit with:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Now, is there a way of using a function such as `rfft` with the offset string functionality (e.g. if I wanted the fft of each "10Min" block in my data)?

I know I can probably do this with groupby or separating the dataframe first, but since pandas' offset string is so easy to use (it is especially useful in my area of real data analysis) I was wondering how one could do it and not lose its functionality.

*EDIT*

If I try `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10D')).apply(np.fft.rfft, axis=0)` it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Comment: The general way to do this is `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10D')).apply(.....)`

Comment: I have tried that before. I try `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10D')).apply(np.fft.rfft, axis=0)` and it gives me this error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`

Comment: @chrisb I edited the question to include this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that fft function changes the shape of the input you can't just apply it directly.  Here would be one way to wrap it.

```
In [331]: def wrap_fft(df):
     ...:     return pd.DataFrame({c:np.fft.rfft(df[c]) for c in df})

In [332]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10D')).apply(wrap_fft)
Out[332]: 
                                                 A  \
2013-01-01 0                    (0.54057835524+0j)   
           1        (3.58718639626-2.07316200855j)   
           2        (1.31007762632+1.22430332479j)   
           3       (4.36758085029-0.236242884113j)   
           4     (-0.0546232575249+2.11668684871j)   
           5                    (1.55071284264+0j)   
2013-01-11 0                    (4.11929430037+0j)   
           1       (-0.93001545894-2.65804406349j)   
           2        (1.20206318744-1.43815460311j)   
           3        (1.24340282215-4.38679576432j)   
           4     (-0.582004943723-0.943867990404j)   
           5                   (-1.81316546447+0j)   
2013-01-21 0                   (-1.49246511083+0j)   
           1      (-1.15010974637+0.527648266336j)   
           2        (-2.5428259911+2.36604684921j)   
           3      (-2.76468733089+0.860053921011j)   
           4       (-1.41328489201-0.36756122307j)   
           5                   (-3.13773122523+0j)   
  .........
```

Comment: Thanks, I find it difficult to understand how groupby works until this day. This worked really well.